# How to get generated keys from a table in php5

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, key

i have a table named address which has attributes (id,house_number,pin_code) id is auto_increment primary key , i am inserting values by

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db','username','password');
$preparedStatement = $connection->prepare("Insert into address (house_number,pin_code) values(?,?)");
$preparedStatement->bindParam(1,$houseNumber);
$preparedStatement->bindParam(2,$pinCode);
$preparedStatement->execute();
```

now i want something like this

```
$insertedId = $preparedStatement->getGeneratedKeys();
```

Comment: Please tell which way do you access your DB - is it PDO ?

Comment: yes $connection = new PDO(param);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$id = $connection->lastInsertId()`

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

> $id = mysql_insert_id();

try above.

Comment: this is deprecated in php5

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
$preparedStatement = $connection->prepare("Insert into address (house_number,pin_code) values(?,?)");
$preparedStatement->execute([$houseNumber,$pinCode]);
$id=$connection->lastInsertId();
```